# FFMPEG format settings for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

```
String[] args = {
          "-i" ,
          path,
          "-codec:v",
          "libx264",
          "-profile:v",
          "high",
          "-preset",
          "slow",
          "-b:v",
          "500k",
          "-maxrate",
          "500k",
          "-bufsize",
          "1000k",
          "-vf",
          "scale=-1:480",
          "-threads",
          "0",
          "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testing.mp4"
};
```

This is the format i am going for. It works fine on some videos. But it failed on one.

**Error code (Dont know why it is so tabbed out)**

```
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
    libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
    libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
    libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
    libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
    libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
    libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
    libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4':
    Metadata:
      major_brand     : isom
      minor_version   : 512
      compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
    Duration: 00:04:41.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1488 kb/s
      Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1100 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
      Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
  [libx264 @ 0xf70c4800] width not divisible by 2 (853x480)
  Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Download/testing.mp4':
    Metadata:
      major_brand     : isom
      minor_version   : 512
      compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
      encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
      Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 2560:2559 DAR 0:0, 25 fps (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
      Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
  Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

As i got it. It complains that                                                                           `[libx264 @ 0xf70c4800] width not divisible by 2 (853x480)` I have no idea how to fix this issue so that every video can work.

The inspiration i got for my format settings comes from: 
https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/

Does anyone have any tips on what i should do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on this thread/post

https://superuser.com/questions/571141/ffmpeg-avconv-force-scaled-output-to-be-divisible-by-2

The solution i got is from Fernando Piancastelli. (Credit to him)
Changing the scaling to `-vf scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480"` solved everything

Comment: `scale="-2:480"` will do the same thing.